# An expression to wish all evil away from someone

Tags: expressions

I am looking for an expression in English to wish all evil away from someone.

Comment: Like: "[May] God bless you."  Or "Stay out of harm's way", "Best of luck [to you]"  "Live long and prosper" (or is that a Vulcan expression)? or (found in a book)(I'd never heard it before) "May the devil never miss you until you are six foot[sic] under"

Comment: 'Have a good day' would raise fewer eyebrows than some of Jim's delightful expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a handful of phrases in English that would qualify but they all depend on what you mean by "evil." If you mean a *literal* evil as in evil spirits, evil powers or evil forces than the only one I know of is:

> God bless.

This is a generic well wishing. More specific religious phrases, blessings and rituals are beyond the scope of this forum.

If you are less concerned about the supernatural and more concerned about random happenstance:

> Best of luck / good luck.
>
> All the best.
>
> May fortune smile upon you.
>
> I wish you well.

And if you are worried about *people* causing evil:

> Stay safe / drive safe / safe travels.
>
> Godspeed.

Answer (score 0):

Three cases :
a) You have have a religion ; then pray your God(s), or His (their) saints, if any, with your own words ;
b) You have no specific creed, but are not too sure about possible supernatural powers : see a witch ;
c) You are an atheist : in that case you know it is utterly useless, but nice to say him/her "all the best", for instance ; at least, it is certified to be harmless.